# ASP Clássico no Windows Azure

Tags: asp, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma aplicação web em ASP Clássico que utiliza uma DLL .NET registrada pelo [regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), um componente de upload ([dundas upload](http://aspalliance.com/dundas/)) e o CDOSYS para enviar emails.

Esta aplicação é acessada por vários clientes e possui conexão com banco de dados SQL Server 2005.

É possível colocar esta aplicação no Windows Azure? E qual seria a melhor solução: Web Site, Virtual Machine ou Cloud Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sua aplicação precisa do registro de DLLs, o ideal é utilizar `Virtual Machine`, pois serão necessárias algumas configurações extras.

Aqui tem os passos para habilitar o ASP Clássico no seu site Azure:

http://khailiangtech.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/windows-azure-how-to-enable-classic-asp-support/

Aqui tem os passos para realizar o procedimento no modo `Virtual Machine`:

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidmcg/5-steps-to-run-a-classic-asp-page-on-windows-azure)

O `regasm` pode ser usado pela Shell sem problemas.

Comment: Olá Cigano.
Eu li que o Cloud Service permite fazer algumas configurações no servidor. Só não sei se esse "pouco" seria o suficiente para instalar componentes e DLLs. (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/)

Comment: Em teoria, uma Virtual Machine permite um grande controle. Não vejo porque isso não seria possível.